# Python Class recursion property decorator

Tags: python, class, recursion, properties, decorator

I am trying to get the MaxNum to be a property of the class Node, but I got "maximum recursion depth exceeded"

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, data=None):
    if data is None:
      data = []
    self.data = data
  
  @property
  def MaxNum(self, nlist=None):
    if nlist == None:
      nlist = self.data
    if len(nlist) == 1:
      return nlist[0]
    else:
      mx = self.MaxNum(nlist[1:])
      return mx if mx > nlist[0] else nlist[0]

  @property
  def MinNum(self):
    mn = self.data[0]
    for n in self.data:
      if n <= mn:
        mn = n
    return mn

def main():
  with open('random_numbers.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    lst = [int(x) for x in f.read().split(",")]
  y = Node(lst)
  print(y.MinNum)
  print(y.MaxNum)
  return
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The MaxNum function alone works well, but when i add the decorator generates error: "maximun recursion depth exceeded".

Comment: You're using @property incorrectly. property is meant to return a value, property.setter is to set a value.

Comment: I would like to return the value of MaxNum... similarly as I did for the function MinNum. The problem is MaxNum uses recursion.. I would like to use recursion still but also able to use the decorator... maybe I need to use another decorator or wrapper. Not sure

Comment: Can you give a small sample of your dataset ?

Comment: "3149","3318","9336","6480". This is going to be passed as a csv file to main. Then main will pass to the class just a list of numbers.

Comment: can you not just use max([int(x) for x in ['3149', '3318', '9336', '6480']]) ?

Comment: yes, I just wanted to use recursion. I know what you mean. Thanks anyway